# PHPMailer not working since uploading website

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Since I have uploaded my website to a server I cannot use PHPMailer to send smtp mails. It worked before on my local server (XAMPP). I am using GMAIL so I also changed all the required gmail settings (i.a. I created another OAuth2 token). Nevertheless, it just won't work...

The PHP code I am using (and which is also working offline) is the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
 */

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

//Load dependencies from composer
//If this causes an error, run 'composer install'
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Load dependencies from composer
//If this causes an error, run 'composer install'
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailerOAuth;

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Set AuthType
$mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';

//User Email to use for SMTP authentication - Use the same Email used in Google Developer Console
$mail->oauthUserEmail = "mygmail@gmail.com";

//Obtained From Google Developer Console
$mail->oauthClientId = "IWONTTELLU.apps.googleusercontent.com";

//Obtained From Google Developer Console
$mail->oauthClientSecret = "IWONTTELLU";

//Obtained By running get_oauth_token.php after setting up APP in Google Developer Console.
//Set Redirect URI in Developer Console as [https/http]://<yourdomain>/<folder>/get_oauth_token.php
// eg: http://localhost/phpmail/get_oauth_token.php
$mail->oauthRefreshToken = "1/IWONTTELLU";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
//For gmail, this generally needs to be the same as the user you logged in as
$mail->setFrom('mygmail@gmail.com', 'BLA');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('my@privatemail.com', 'Hi');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

When I try to use it online, it first of all takes very long until I get an error (tried to use `gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com')`, too; long story short: didn't work, too) and secondly, the code I get is `Error: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)` & `SMTP connect() failed`. The service I am using is provided by 1and1 (1und1/1&1). I've been trying to fix this for more than 4 hours now and can't find out what is wrong. Less secure apps can access and I also created a token and "created" a refresh token as in https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2 . The Troubleshooting guide (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) couldn't really help me as well although I think it has problems with authenticating... I have also tried to use ssl (of course I also changed the port etc.) which didn't work either.

Comment: I would recommend adding debugging code in there and figure out if you are getting a PHP error (check PHP log if you have one). It could be alot of things, so removing the obvious ones helps get closer to a solution. A general timeout message is not helping. I would also just check the authentication piece and see if you are getting a valid status code.

Answer (score 0):

Is port 587 still supported by gmail? You might want to you SSL port 465. This article might also be useful https://www.wpsitecare.com/gmail-smtp-settings/ or perhaps 1&1 is being blocked by gmail? See this post http://docs.mailpoet.com/article/61-sending-with-gmail-doesnt-work

Comment: As I said, it is working offline... I will contact 1&1 tomorrow so I won't be able to tell if it isn't working because they blocked the port...

Comment: If you are working locally, why would 1&1 have something to do with it, unless you mean that they provide your internet connection and have noticed that you are trying to access port 587 ... which I doubt.

Comment: No, I tested all my code offline and also tested if the new tokens I created were working which they did (localhost)... I uploaded my website to 1&1 today and can't send emails online (via this website) which I could on a local server, that's the problem.

Comment: Okay, understood. I do think you should try another port. 465 is better anyway, security wise. But yes, ring them up ... if you get through ;)